# Firefox gBrowser.selectedBrowser ID

Tags: firefox

I'm working on developing a Firefox extension. In my extension I'm using an array to store some specific data depending on tabs.

I used:

```
gBrowser.getBrowserIndexForDocument(gBrowser.contentDocument);
```

For getting the TabID.

What I found is that the TabID could exist more the one time if I open Firefox more then one time. What I need would be something like gBrowser.selectedBrowser BrowserID.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store your data as a property on a tab/browser element or the content document.